# Excel while import adding the empty row into the database in PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I import the excel sheet and inserting the data into the database and it's working.

My issue is, I have 10 records in the excel sheet, and the remaining all empty. Now when I import the sheet then I am getting the empty records in the database.

Excel sheet format:

[image]

Database:

[image]

Code:

```
function importsheet($pdo){
if($_FILES["list21"]["name"] != '')
{
   $allowed_extension = array('xls', 'csv', 'xlsx');
   $file_array = explode(".", $_FILES["list21"]["name"]);
   $file_extension = end($file_array);

   if(in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension))
   {
    $file_name = time() . '.' . $file_extension;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['list21']['tmp_name'], $file_name);
    $file_type = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file_name);
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($file_type);

    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file_name);

    unlink($file_name);

  $data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
  // echo "<pre>";
  // print_r($data);
   
    $isheader = 0;
    foreach($data as $row)
    {


    if($isheader > 0) {
     $insert_data = array(
      ':name'  => $row[0],
      ':slug'=>slugGenerator($row[0]),
      ':city'  => $row[1],
      ':size'  => $row[2],
      ':about'  => $row[3],
      ':email'  => $row[4],
      ':meta_keyword'  => $row[5],
      ':meta_desc'  => $row[6],
      ':page_title'  => $row[7],
     );

 $query = "INSERT INTO `list`(`name`, `slug`, `city`, `size`, `about`, `email`, `meta_keyword`, `meta_desc`,`page_title`) VALUES (:name,:slug,:city,:size,:about,:email,:meta_keyword,:meta_desc,:page_title)";

 $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute($insert_data);
     }
  else 
    {

     $isheader = 1;

      }

    } // foreach
    $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Data Imported Successfully</div>';

   } //in_array

   else
   {
    $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xls .csv or .xlsx file allowed</div>';
   }

}
else
{
 $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please Select File</div>';
}

echo $message;

}
```

Comment: You could check if the values are empty before you insert them. If they are empty, call `continue;` to tell the loop to jump to the next iteration.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Rows are not empty but maybe I have a column empty. Where should I add the continue?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I added the screenshot of the first column in the question.

Comment: You need to define how a row is empty in your eyes. As a help: is a row empty if 1 column is ''? Is a row empty if email is '' and pagetitle is ''? Is a row empty if every single value is ''? And so on. Lets say you define row is empty as email is '' and pagetitle is '': right after `foreach($data as $row) {` add `if ($row[4] == '' && $row[7] == '') {continue;}`

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal, For the testing purpose, I filled all the columns(10 rows) and uploaded them also I am getting the 996 records in the database.

Comment: I just print the  $data and comment out all for each then also I am getting empty.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I have noticed that if I use CSV file then it's working perfectly but if I use xls then it's not working. then I am getting empty row,